# link hide when the user starts to scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make this down-link fade when user scrolls the page? I'm guessing this would be done with jQuery but I'm not very familiar with that.

HTML

```
<div class="down-link"><a class="w-downlink" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
```

CSS

```
.w-downlink {
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
float:right;
margin-right:30px;
font-weight:bolder;
line-height: 50px;
height: 30px;
padding-top:15px;
color:#FFF;
width:50px;
opacity:0.7; transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
 background-color: #333;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}

.w-downlink.active {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.w-downlink:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

.down-link {
float: none;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 170px;
}
```

WORKING J QUERY CODE

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
   $('.down-link').fadeOut(250);
 } else {
   $('.down-link').fadeIn(0);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('.down-link').fadeTo("slow" , 0); 
});
```

if you want it back when you come back up use this instead

```
$(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var nowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - nowScrollTop) >= delta){
            if (nowScrollTop > lastScrollTop){
                $('.down-link').fadeTo('slow',0); // scrolling down
            } else {
                $('.down-link').fadeTo('slow',1); // scrolling up
            }
            lastScrollTop = nowScrollTop;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that's great only thing is is does't return when if the user is back at the top of the page. If you imagine i have a link that scroll down when the user is at the top of the page. I would like that to disappear when the user scrolls when the back to top link appears (which is fully working). but need it to reappear if back at the top of the page. @lili

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I answered with the assumption that this question would get deleted because it shows poor research from the original poster as it is only about using a standard jquery function and this question has been posted many times earlier.

Comment: its not a generic comment @loli you mong. it was a genine request for help/support about a topic i know very little about. having read your comment i have managed to understand what thought process i need to follow and have actually managed to solve the problem with the code i've added.

Comment: please stop cyber-bullying me or I will call the police :^)